# How can I ignore tags?

Tags: support, ignored-tags

I'm getting tired of seeing all of the "Laravel" questions here by noobs whose questions fall under the category of "Why isn't this code working?" It is border line spam.

Can we ban this tag and all questions, or can I block all Laravel questions?

Comment: Help Center: http://stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics

Answer (score 10):

Just go to your profile, the preferences-tab, and add them to "Ignored Tags":

Here a link for the main SO site:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/me